# How to train auto encoder with noise

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have an auto encoder with 2 encoder blocks and one concatenation block and 1 decoder block. the reconstruction works fine for my simulated data with 0 added noise. Even if the Gaussian noise with a very small standard deviation is added, the model performs poorly. How do I solve this?

Input - simulated data that visually represents blocks of data like biclusters.
Input layers in each block - 3 layers

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size_encoder1, input_size_encoder2):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        torch.manual_seed(1)

        # Encoder 1
        self.encoder1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size_encoder1, input_size_encoder1),
            nn.Linear(input_size_encoder1, 10),
            nn.Linear(10, 1)
        )

        # Encoder 2
        self.encoder2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size_encoder2, input_size_encoder2),
            nn.Linear(input_size_encoder2, 10),
            nn.Linear(10, 1)
        )

        # Decoder
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2,2),
            nn.Linear(2, 10),
            nn.Linear(10, 1),
        )

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        # Encoding
        encoded1 = self.encoder1(x1)
        encoded2 = self.encoder2(x2)

        # Concatenate the encodings
        concatenated_output = torch.cat((encoded1, encoded2), dim=1)

        # Decoding
        decoded = self.decoder(concatenated_output)

        return decoded

    learning_rate = 0.001
    epochs = 100
    reg_hyperparameter = 1e-10
    batch_size = 200
```

I have experimented with adding more layers and changing batch_size, epochs and learning rate. None seem to show promising results. Can someone point to where I should start looking at least?

Comment: Can you show the code that adds the noise?

Comment: Where are you adding the noise? If you are adding noise to the input and expecting the autoencoder to denoise your image, you'll have to retrain the model to remove noise, not reconstruct it.